# How can i auto load .net DLL on AutoCAD startup

Tags: .net, dll, autoload, autocad

I created a plugin for AutoCAD and make its .net DLL, I wanted to autoload DLL on AutoCAD startup/run. without typing netload command in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add registry entries to get it to load. You can find the details here https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-autoload-DLLs-with-AutoCAD.html

Comment: While links are great in an answer, a good answer should quote the relevant parts of the linked documentation. See [Provide Context for Links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ways shown in the link provided by Joel Lucsy, you can use the Autoloader mechanism:
https://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/01/autodesk-autoloader-white-paper.html